# Java stream mp3 from bytes

Tags: java, mp3

How to stream mp3 from bytes ? I'm getting the bytes from a file, but then how to start the sound ?

```
     File file = new File(a);
     FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
      byte get_inside[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(fin.read(get_inside)));
```

This is the sample code of byte getting and the **a**  is the file .

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Java Sound API or the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). See the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) for an example of the Java Sound API.

Note that you shouldn't just call `InputStream.read` *once* and assume you'll get the complete data, by the way - regardless of whether this is an MP3 or not.

Comment: i will see it , yes it is mp3

Comment: @user639285: My point is that you should *never* just assume that a single call to `read` will read everything you've asked for.

Comment: The Java Sound API combined with the `mp3plugin.jar` of the JMF will be enough.  If the `mp3plugin.jar` is on the run-time class path of the app., Java Sound will be able to read MP3s.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in my pure Java mp3 player: [mp3transform](http://code.google.com/p/mp3transform/).